# Finding highest high bar_index between two previously calculated indicators

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to implement fractals to find support and resistance levels. I can find the "support" fractals with the following code:

```
//@version=4
study("Fractals v1", overlay=true, max_bars_back=300)

var offset = input(defval=2, title='depth', type=input.integer, minval=2, maxval=3)

add_to_array(arr, val) =>
    array.shift(arr)
    array.push(arr, val)

//======================= Support levels =========================================================================================================================================================================

var previous_lows = array.new_int(3)

support_at_depth_2() =>
    a = low[0]
    b = low[1]
    c = low[2] // mid point - we are checking if this low is the lowest in the set 0-4
    d = low[3] 
    e = low[4]
    
    leftSide = c <= b and c <= a ? true : false
    rightSide = c <= d and c <= e ? true : false
    result = leftSide and rightSide
    add_to_array(previous_lows, bar_index[2])
    result


support_at_depth_3() =>
    a = low[0]
    b = low[1]
    c = low[2]
    d = low[3] // mid point - we are checking if this low is the lowest in the set 0-6
    e = low[4]
    f = low[5]
    g = low[6]
    leftSide = d <= c and d <= b and d <= a ? true : false
    rightSide = d <= e and d <= f and d <= g ? true : false
    result = leftSide and rightSide
    add_to_array(previous_lows, bar_index[3])
    result // return bool


support = offset == 2 ? support_at_depth_2() : support_at_depth_3()

plotshape(support, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.olive, size = size.small, offset=-offset)
```

Plotted on the tradingview chart:
[image]

---

I have implemented the same logic for "resistance" fractals BUT this sometimes produces results that I do not want - the example is two "resistance fractals" appearing side by side.

What I want to achieve is a pattern of

- "high, low, high, low, high, low..."

...and NOT:

- "high, low, HIGH, HIGH, low, high, low..."

So the added code would be:

```
var previous_highs = array.new_int(3)

resistance_at_depth_2() =>
    a = high[0]
    b = high[1]
    c = high[2] // mid point - we are checking if this low is the lowest in the set 0-4
    d = high[3] 
    e = high[4]
    
    leftSide = c >= b and c >= a ? true : false
    rightSide = c >= d and c >= e ? true : false
    result = leftSide and rightSide
    add_to_array(previous_highs, bar_index[2])
    result


resistance_at_depth_3() =>
    a = high[0]
    b = high[1]
    c = high[2]
    d = high[3] // mid point - we are checking if this low is the lowest in the set 0-6
    e = high[4]
    f = high[5]
    g = high[6]
    leftSide = d >= c and d >= b and d >= a ? true : false
    rightSide = d >= e and d >= f and d >= g ? true : false
    result = leftSide and rightSide
    add_to_array(previous_highs, bar_index[3])
    result // return bool


resistance = offset == 2 ? resistance_at_depth_2() : resistance_at_depth_3()

plotshape(resistance, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size = size.small, offset=-offset)
```

As I stated this sometimes results in the incorrect pattern I'm looking for, as shown in the fig below:
[image]

---

My thinking on how to solve this pattern issue would be to simply find the highest high between two "support" fractals (green up arrows) and plotshape() at it's bar_index. I have attempted (with little success) to implement something that resembles my idea but to no avail yet.

?- Can I grab the period between the current support and the previous support and loop over the bars within that range to then try and grab the highest `high` and it's `bar_index`?

I'm new to pine script and in other programming languages (Python/JavaScript) on each bar I would save the bar details in to a dict/object and them push into an array. I would then iterate over the array finding each support level (using fractals method as above) and add support = true to each dict/object when applicable, I could then iterate over the list/array again to infill the highest high between each support == true. With pine script I feel that these options (currently) are a little limited and I'll have to find the 'nuances' and work arounds for pine script.

I appreciate any pointers or help on this (and pine script in general), or even if this can be implemented using much simpler methods in pine script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use an additional float array to store the pivot prices as well as the bar index, and a `var bool` to track whether the last pivot that occurred was "resistance" or "support".

If for example you get consecutive resistance pivots you can then compare the last resistance added to the array to the new resistance pivot and if the new one is higher, use `array.set` to modify the most recent array element rather than add a new pivot to the arrays.

If the new resistance pivot is lower you would not add anything to the arrays, keeping the previous pivot only.

If the previous event was a support pivot you would add a new resistance pivot to the resistance arrays regardless of the previously stored resistance value.

You will also need to use label arrays instead of `plotshape()` so that you can delete or move a previous resistance pivot marker label when that older resistance pivot is then followed by a consecutive higher pivot.